# How to give height in the footer in the Ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have updated my ng-grid to the ag-grid i want to give fix footer row height as in ng-grid it is "footerRowHeight"

How to do the same in the ag-grid.

Thank you in the advance, Hoping for the quick reply...

Comment: I am facing this issue too. Please help me

Comment: Any Update on this Question ??

Comment: In the new update of the grid there is a option like gridOptions.rowHeight  to give the height to the row , with this how can we give height to the footer  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that i am responding very late, But this might be helpful to others who might be struggling with the same question.

We can use below options:

- rowClass: Property to set CSS class for all rows. Provide either a
  string (class name) or array of string (array of class names).
- getRowClass: Callback to set class for each row individually.

In the CSS we can give height or min-height based on the requirement.

Reference [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/).

Comment: how do you identify a footer row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any parameters that suggest you can at http://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/index.php

Since it's floating rows in the bottom of the grid. The rowHeight must be the one you need to use, but it'll affect all rows.

You can open an issue on the ag-grid github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid option `getRowHeight` to assign a fix row height to your group row footer.

Suppose your grid is grouped by `country` property

```
getRowHeight: function(params) {
   // If grouping row
   if (params.node.field === 'country') {
      return 32;
   } 
   // Ordinary row
   else {
      return 25;
   }
}
```